# FreeBSD inkscape installation

Tags: freebsd

During installation of inkscape from ports on FreeBSD I get this error: 
Looks like inscape among other installs ghostscript9-base which triggeres an error. See compilation process below:

```
===>  Installing for ghostscript9-base-9.06_11
===>   ghostscript9-base-9.06_11 depends on file: /usr/local/share/ghostscript/fonts/a010013l.pfb - found
===>   ghostscript9-base-9.06_11 depends on shared library: libexpat.so - found (/usr/local/lib/libexpat.so)
===>   ghostscript9-base-9.06_11 depends on shared library: libfreetype.so - found (/usr/local/lib/libfreetype.so)
===>   ghostscript9-base-9.06_11 depends on shared library: libidn.so - found (/usr/local/lib/libidn.so)
===>   ghostscript9-base-9.06_11 depends on shared library: libjbig2dec.so - found (/usr/local/lib/libjbig2dec.so)
===>   ghostscript9-base-9.06_11 depends on shared library: liblcms2.so - found (/usr/local/lib/liblcms2.so)
===>   ghostscript9-base-9.06_11 depends on shared library: libpaper.so - found (/usr/local/lib/libpaper.so)
===>   ghostscript9-base-9.06_11 depends on shared library: libpng.so - found (/usr/local/lib/libpng.so)
===>   ghostscript9-base-9.06_11 depends on shared library: libtiff.so - found (/usr/local/lib/libtiff.so)
===>   ghostscript9-base-9.06_11 depends on shared library: libfontconfig.so - found (/usr/local/lib/libfontconfig.so)
===>   ghostscript9-base-9.06_11 depends on shared library: libcupsimage.so - found (/usr/local/lib/libcupsimage.so)
===>   ghostscript9-base-9.06_11 depends on shared library: libvga.so - found (/usr/local/lib/libvga.so)
===>   ghostscript9-base-9.06_11 depends on shared library: libjpeg.so - found (/usr/local/lib/libjpeg.so)
===>   ghostscript9-base-9.06_11 depends on shared library: libiconv.so - found (/usr/local/lib/libiconv.so)
===>  Checking if ghostscript9-base already installed
===>   Registering installation for ghostscript9-base-9.06_11 as automatic
Installing ghostscript9-base-9.06_11...
pkg-static: ghostscript9-base-9.06_11 conflicts with ghostscript9-nox11-9.06_10 (installs files into the same place).  Problematic file: /usr/local/bin/dvipdf
*** Error code 70

Stop in /usr/ports/print/ghostscript9-base.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/print/ghostscript9-base.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/print/texlive-base.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/print/texlive-texmf.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/print/tex-formats.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/devel/doxygen.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/devel/doxygen.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/textproc/librevenge.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/textproc/librevenge.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/graphics/inkscape.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/graphics/inkscape.
```

Could you please advice on how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 3):

The `/usr/ports/UPDATING` file contains following entry:

> 20150822:
>   AFFECTS: users of print/ghostscript*
>   AUTHOR:
>   hrs@FreeBSD.org
>
> print/ghostscript{7,8,9,9-agpl} have been split into 
>   print/ghostscript{7,8,9,9-agpl}-{base,x11}.  print/ghostscript*-nox11
>   ports have been removed.
>
> The -base installs Ghostscript binaries, libgs, and other data files 
>   and it depends on no X11 library.  The -x11 installs a small shared 
>   library to enable x11* devices in the installed -base package.
>
> In most cases, Ghostscript is installed as a dependency.  A
>   port/package  which requires Ghostscript will automatically pick up
>   -base, and  when x11* devices required it will pick up -x11 in addition.
>
> If one wants to install Ghostscript manually and full compatibility 
>   with the previous versions, just install -x11 because it installs 
>   -base as a dependency.  Combination of the two provides the same  functionality as before.

So, you need to run `pkg delete -f ghostscript9-nox11` first and then proceed with inkscape installation.